# É possível criar um ListView Android Horizontal?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Problema**

Estou necessitando implementar um `ListView` horizontal, para criar uma barra de navegação horizontal sobre minha Galeria de produtos em meu Catalogo de Vendas. Com a intenção de tornar a navegação mas intuitiva e fácil por parte dos usuários.

Mas para minha surpresa me parece que o `ListView` não tem suporte a horizontal navegação.

**Implementação pretendida (Para entender melhor o cenario)**

Minha solução utilizando `ListView` horizontal seria coloca-lo sobre minha galeria (com `RelativeLayout`), e popula-lo com miniaturas das imagens dos produtos do Catalogo, permitindo assim a navegação através dele, além do *scroll* horizontal sobre a galeria.

**Perguntas?**

- Há alguma maneira de tornar o `ListView` horizontal?
- Há alguma maneira melhor de resolver meu problema sem utilizar `ListView`;

**Informações adicionais**

Estou utilizando para implementar minha galeria [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery).

Comment: Aconselho utilizar a biblioteca HorizontalVariableListView. Sugiro procurar no github o repositório da biblioteca.

Comment: Você já utilizou esta biblioteca?

Comment: Utilizo essa biblioteca sim. Antes utilizava a biblioteca TwoWayGridView mas agora estou utilizando essa. Continua tendo suporte e tem desempenho melhor. @fernando

Comment: O mais recomendado é usar o Recycler View Nessa resposta vc pode ver como implementar corretamente
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953855/7069639](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953855/7069639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usei essa api em projeto e funcionou legal

Link para download: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Sua activity fica assim

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

    HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
    "Text #2",
    "Text #3" }; 

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataObjects.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        return retval;
    }

};
```

}

Seu layout fica assim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#fff"
 >

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
     android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#ddd"
  />

 </LinearLayout>
```

ListItem para customizar fica assim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#fff"
   >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="150dip"
      android:layout_height="150dip"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
     />

      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Aqui tem um tutorial explicando http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Comment: Olá @IgorRonner. Consegue melhorar sua resposta para que fique  possível de entender sem depender de links externos?

Comment: @gpupo, como faço para editar a minha resposta?

Comment: Ao final da resposta existe um link ``editar``

Comment: @IgorRonner, estou utilizando uma variação que encontrei de seu link, que é [essa](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView), estou tentando resolver algumas limitações como centralizar ao centro da view no caso de houver poucos itens (Hoje está ficando alinhado sempre a esquerda não importa o que eu faça). Mas me parece ser uma limitação do próprio ListView como está aberto [nessa questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26847/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-listview-crescer-horizontalmente-somente-o-tamanho-de-seu-conte)

Comment: Essa questão de alinhamento você corrigi na View do Item.